# Block specified URLs

Tags: delphi

I want to write an application in Delphi which filters requested URLs in the OS (not only web browsers) and if it matches - blocks it or changes the URL's content to blank. The problem is - I don't know where to start looking. Could you help me with some informations?

Comment: I can't find it right now, but this has been discussed quite well already on SO in at least one question. Maybe play with search terms for a while... Terms like `content filter`, `whitelisting`, `blacklisting` come to mind.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're talking about a DNS service. usually, DNS services live outside, on your router, your ISP, or a 3rd-party like www.openDNS.org
But you could write your own, run it on your PC, and set your internet settings to use that as your DNS server.
I suspect that a lot of malware works like this....

Also, this sort of thing can be done with no programming at all - just edit your hosts file in C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts  (it's a text file with no extension).
Anything in there should trump.

Also, before you start writing an application to do this, have a look at OpenDNS. If it's an app for personal use, you may find that you don't need it. If it's going to be a commercial offering, this is the bar for usability and usefulness that you need to meet or beat.

Comment: I thought the OP was after a "Parental Control" type of application, where you selectively deny access to certain URLs. It can certainly be done using the `hosts` file, but there should be some other ways. I doubt the "Parental Control" type of applications rely on the hosts file: the hosts file would get huge and it would give the controlled kid a place to look for the good stuff!

Comment: so you know, I didn't downvote. I really don't get those anonymous downvotes.

Comment: very rude anonymours downvoters... voted +1 to balance you back.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.mail-archive.com/delphi-talk@elists.org/msg01558.html - text by Francois PIETTE quoted bellow(in case link will become unavailable):

> "There are several way to achieve your goal. The two main I see are:
>   1) Write a LSP (Layered Service Provider)
>   2) Write a proxy server
>
> The first is not possible with Delphi (At least I think so. If anyone know 
>   how to write a LSP using Delphi, I would love to get the code).
>
> The second - writing a proxy - is more or less easy with Delphi using ICS 
>   components. See "usermade" link at ICS website (http://www.overbyte.be). 
>   With this option, you have to configure IE to use the proxy: IE Menu / Tools 
>   / Internet options / Connections / Network parameters / Use a proxy and then 
>   enter the IP address (127.0.0.1 if proxy run on the same computer) and port 
>   number (pick anyone you like, for example 8080). Once IE is configured to 
>   use a proxy, it will send all requests to the proxy. Then the proxy will 
>   make the real request to the target server and return data back to IE. What 
>   is important there is that you get all URL entered in IE or indirectly use 
>   (clicking on links), and you can either really rely them to the target 
>   server or forge and answer your self to say the page access is denied.
>
> At ICS website, on the usermade page, you'll even find a HTTP proxy 
>   component. If you need help with this component and/or the entire ICS, 
>   please use ICS support mailing list (same server as this list). See 
>   "support" link at ICS website for support details."

LE: it seems that this question is possible a duplicate
[Using delphi to block websites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646099/using-delphi-to-block-websites)

Comment: Cosmin, I did not claim that is my text! that was the reason why I have put the link on the top of the answer...anyway, I suspect that this question is a duplicate.

Comment: Everything you write on SO gets you signature at the bottom-right; Unless you specifically say you're quoting someone else, it's your own.

Answer (score 0):

use GetExtendedTcpTable api locate if there are any connexions to the remote server you want to block on port 80 if there is a connection use SetTcpEntry to terminate that connexion is pretty simple

Comment: I don't think that would work, for many reasons: (a) Pooling might miss some connections because you can't constantly pool and HTTP sessions aren't necessarily very long lived. (b) Pooling should generally be used as a last resort. (c) There's no 1:1 mapping between URL's and IP's. Every URL points to a single IP, but there are servers running hundreds of sites on a single IP address.